# Query not returning all tags

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I try to query a row for a specific tag, I get the correct row but I don't get all the row's tags. However, when I remove the query for the tag and just search by 'name' I get the correct row + all the row's tags.

```
SELECT communities.name,array_agg(community_tags.tag) as tag 
FROM communities INNER JOIN community_tags on communities.id = community_tags.community_id 
WHERE 
    communities.name = '' OR
    community_tags.tag = 'asdf'
GROUP BY communities.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.name, array_agg(ct.tag) as tag 
FROM communities c INNER JOIN
     community_tags ct
     on c.id = ct.community_id 
WHERE to_tsvector(c.name) @@ to_tsquery('') OR 
      to_tsvector(c.description) @@ to_tsquery('')    
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING bool_or(to_tsvector(ct.tag) @@ to_tsquery('asdf'))
```

Comment: This doesn't return any rows. I also removed the extra OR

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with

```
SELECT f_c.name,array_agg(community_tags.tag) FROM community_tags,
    (
        SELECT communities.*
        FROM communities INNER JOIN community_tags on communities.id = community_tags.community_id 
        WHERE
            to_tsvector(community_tags.tag) @@ to_tsquery('asdf') OR
            to_tsvector(communities.name) @@ to_tsquery('') OR 
            to_tsvector(communities.description) @@ to_tsquery('')
        GROUP BY communities.id
    ) as f_c
    WHERE f_c.id = community_tags.community_id
    GROUP BY f_c.name
```